# MySql Query Super Slow

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following query which is super slow (taking 4-5 seconds just for the results. I was wondering if anyone could see anything that I could do differently with this query to speed it up?

Thanks!

```
SELECT
accounts.id AS account_id,
accounts. NAME AS account_name,
accounts.assigned_user_id account_id_owner,
users.user_name AS assigned_user_name,
opportunities_cstm.firstname_c, opportunities_cstm.lastname_c,
opportunities.`name`, TRIM(
    Concat(
        Ifnull(
            opportunities_cstm.firstname_c,
            ''
        ),
        ' ',
        Ifnull(
            opportunities_cstm.lastname_c,
            ''
        )
    )
) AS 'cfull' FROM
opportunities 
LEFT JOIN users ON opportunities.assigned_user_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN accounts_opportunities ON opportunities.id = accounts_opportunities.opportunity_id 
LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts_opportunities.account_id = accounts.id
LEFT JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
WHERE
(
    (
        opportunities.sales_stage IN (
            'Prospecting',
            'Appointment Set',
            'MeetAndGreet',
            'Qualification',
            'Needs Analysis',
            'Locating Vehicle',
            'Demo',
            'Trade Evaluation',
            'Negotiation',
            'Manager T/O',
            'Write Up',
            'Credit App Submitted',
            'Pending Finance',
            'Loan Approval',
            'Deposit',
            'Delayed Decision',
            'Sold-Vehicle Ordered',
            'Sold-Pending Finance',
            'Sold/Pending Delivery',
            'Price Quoted',
            'Service Pending'
        )
    )
)
AND (
accounts_opportunities.deleted IS NULL
OR accounts_opportunities.deleted = 0
)
AND (
accounts.deleted IS NULL
OR accounts.deleted = 0
)
AND opportunities.deleted = 0
ORDER BY
opportunities.date_entered DESC,
opportunities.id DESC
LIMIT 0,21
```

Here is the explain from the same query:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════════════════╦════════╦══════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║ select_type ║         table          ║  type  ║      possible_keys       ║         key         ║ key_len ║                    ref                     ║ rows  ║            extra            ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════╣
║ simple      ║ opportunities          ║ range  ║ sales_stage, idx_deleted ║ sales_stage         ║      78 ║ null                                       ║ 25161 ║ Using where; Using filesort ║
║ simple      ║ users                  ║ eq_ref ║ PRIMARY, idx_id_deleted  ║ PRIMARY             ║     108 ║ version4.opportunities.assigned_user_id    ║     1 ║                             ║
║ simple      ║ accounts_opportunities ║ ref    ║ idx_oppid_del_accid      ║ idx_oppid_del_accid ║     111 ║ version4.opportunities.id                  ║     1 ║ Using where; Using index    ║
║ simple      ║ accounts               ║ eq_ref ║ PRIMARY,idx_accnt_id_del ║ PRIMARY             ║     108 ║ version4.accounts_opportunities.account_id ║     1 ║ Using where                 ║
║ simple      ║ opportunities_cstm     ║ eq_ref ║ PRIMARY                  ║ PRIMARY             ║     108 ║ version4.opportunities.id                  ║     1 ║                             ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════════════╩════════╩══════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: `Using filesort` is the worst.

Comment: Yeah, if you see `Using filesort` you're basically dead in the water, especially with a large number of affected rows. You're going to have to look at ways of incorporating an index on your `ORDER` columns.

Comment: What indexes do you have set up already?

Comment: Here are my indexes on the opportunities table. What could be done differently to avoid using filesort? We have a ton of memory and it's not being maxed out so I know it's not resorting to file based tables, etc. Here is a link to the indexes screenshot I took: http://d.pr/i/7oEz

Comment: `Using filesort` does NOT mean it's going to disk; it means it's necessary to sort a derived result set.  That's generally the case when you use `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` on a big fat join like you have.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems.

First, you're using two different `WHERE (... IS NULL OR ... = 0)` criteria.  Those are unspeakably slow.  This is because indexes aren't useful for looking for NULL values. If you can get rid of the possibility of NULL in those `deleted` columns, perhaps by declaring them `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` you can change those criteria to `WHERE ... = 0`. This should speed up lots of things. This is because indexes aren't useful for looking for NULL values.

Second, you're creating a great big joined result set, then sorting it to find the most recent items.

You might try preselecting the items from your 'opportunities' table before you do your join.  Do something like this:

```
SELECT   whatever....
FROM (
         SELECT * 
           FROM opportunities
          WHERE opportunities.deleted = 0
            AND opportunities.sales_stage IN (
            'Prospecting',
            'Appointment Set',  etc etc  ...
            'Service Pending' )
       ORDER BY opportunities.date_entered DESC,
                opportunities.id DESC
          LIMIT 0,21
      ) opportunities 
LEFT JOIN users ON opportunities.assigned_user_id = users.id
...
ORDER BY
opportunities.date_entered DESC,
opportunities.id DESC
LIMIT 0,21
```

This very possibly could speed things up by reducing the cardinality of your LEFT JOIN operation by removing a bunch of records from the right-hand side of the join.

Comment: I would also add that a multi column index on date_entered, deleted, and sales_stage (in that order) would probably help as well.  I really wish MySQL would implement descending sorted indexes.

Comment: Ollie - Thanks for the feedback. I just tried the query you provided above. But, I received an error message.Here is the error I received:<pre>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN users ON opportunities.assigned_user_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN accounts' at line 37</pre>

Comment: I didn't have a chance to debug my query, sorry to say.  (I don't have your data.)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use IN. IN works slow in mysql, use Exists

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable ( sales_stage VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL );
insert into tempTable () values ('Prospecting'),('Appointment Set'),('MeetAndGreet'),...,('Service Pending');

SELECT
...
WHERE EXISTS(select sales_stage from tempTable where opportunities.sales_stage = sales_stage);
```

Comment: Boris - I am not sure how I would use exists on a field. Can you please explain?

Comment: Could you please explain "IN works slow in mysql"?  I would agree if the IN was a subquery... but I have to disagree in this case because because he is using a list of literal values.

Comment: look here please http://www.jortk.nl/2008/07/exists-much-faster-then-in-in-mysql/ and here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it would make any improvement, but what I would try is this:

```
SELECT your_fields
FROM
  (SELECT * --or just the fields you need
   FROM
     opportunities
   WHERE
     opportunities.deleted = 0 AND
     opportunities.sales_stage IN (stage1, stage2, ...)
  ) opportunities1
  LEFT JOIN users ON opportunities1.assigned_user_id = users.id 
  LEFT JOIN accounts_opportunities ON opportunities1.id = ...etc...
WHERE
  (accounts_opportunities.deleted IS NULL
   OR accounts_opportunities.deleted = 0)
  AND (accounts.deleted IS NULL OR accounts.deleted = 0)
ORDER BY ...etc...
```

Let me know if it makes any improvement (but it could also be slower). Another idea is to use a table with all the stages you need to filter:

```
CREATE TABLE filter_stage (
  stage varchar(255));
```

(255 or try to match the actual length of sales_stage, and it's better if you index this column also) where you enter all the strings to filter:

```
INSERT INTO filter_stage VALUES ('Prospecting'), ('Appointment Set'), ('...'), ...
```

then you remove your IN clause from your first query, and your FROM then becomes:

```
FROM
  opportunities INNER JOIN filter_stage
  ON opportunities.sales_stage = filter_stage.stage
  LEFT JOIN ...
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: fthiella - I tried your example but it made it longer. About 6-7 seconds this time.

Comment: @swhitlow sometimes it works, but it can happen that this makes it slower... did you also try to use a filter_stage table? but without the actual data I can't suggest you much else... what i suggest you do is to try to use different combinations of subqueries, or try to group joined tables with parentheses...